# Abort trap: 6 ERROR

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
 #define ll long long int
 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
      ll t;
      cin >> t;
      ll res[t];
      for(ll k = 0; k < t; k++)
      {
           ll n, cnt = 0;
           ll arr[4] = {0};
           cin >> n;
           for(ll i = 0; i < (1<<n); i++)
           {
                ll x = 0;
                ll chk = 0;
                for(ll j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                     if(i & (1<<j))
                     {
                          chk++;
                          arr[x] = j+1;
                          x++;
                     }
                }
                if(chk == 2)
                {
                     if((arr[0] ^ arr[1]) <= n)
                          cnt++;
                }
           }
           res[k] = cnt;
           // cout << cnt << "\n";
      }
      for(ll i = 0; i < t; i++)
           cout << res[i] << "\n";
      return 0;
 }
```

The program is crashing at run time. The program is running in some test cases but crashes after printing the result. The online compiler is giving stack smash detection error. My computer is giving abort trap: 6 error on the terminal. Please help.

Comment: so - remove the junk and we get - "this program crashes at run time". What platform? Did you run it under your debugger?

Comment: the program is giving the correct answer in some of the cases but aborts after printing the result.

Comment: This isn't valid C++.  C++ does not have dynamic length arrays.

Comment: which one of my questions was that supposed to answer?

Comment: This is classic "online judge" code and question.  Weird usage of `#define` macros, no input cases, usage of non-standard variable length arrays, and the question is about hunting for test cases that break the code.

Comment: @pm100 platform : macOS and no debugger

Comment: 3 forloops nested; with long long's ... how many years did you have to wait for this?

Comment: I am a beginner. Please help me.

Comment: You are writing to an array out-of-bounds somewhere.   The logic and variable names make your code very hard to read or follow.  Look at `arr[x] = j+1;`.  Is `x` ever more than 3?  Why is that array size 4?  What does the 4 mean?

Comment: change the arrays to vectors and use `vector.at` instead of `vector[]` to set and get elements. That will do range checks for you.

Comment: @MAVERICK -- Advice -- get rid of the variable length arrays.  Use `std::vector` instead.  Then replace all of the usage of `[ ]` with `at()` to detect if you're going out-of-bounds somewhere.  (pm100 beat me to it)

Comment: `#define ll long long int` - `typedef` was the preferred way in the 1980's ... `using` is now ... `#define` is not the tool for the job

Comment: @DrewDormann Yeah, you are right. Apparently arr[4] is going out of bound. Thank You.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I will keep that in mind and use it. Thank You.

Comment: @UKMonkey Got it. I will try it out.

Comment: If you need to use macros for abbreviations, I highly recommend you take a keyboarding or typing class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the array arr[4] is going out of bound.